# Is there a way to send a variable from a client.js file to your node.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, fetch, body-parser

I am trying to pass in a product number from my client to my server so I can save it to a database. I've tried almost 100 different ways to print out the "prod" variable but nothing is working.

I already have body-parser and other things included in my code. Is there some small thing I'm doing wrong? if so how should I edit my client file or server file to be able to pass in "prod" from the client to server.

As of right now if just says `undefined`

**Client.js:**

```
    function addToCart(prod1) { 
     fetch( '/addToCart' , { method: ' POST ', body: ' prod= ' + prod1 }); 
    }
```

**server.js:**

```
    app.post("/addToCart", (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body.prod);
    });
```

I expect whatever "prod" is, to be visible in my server file file when I console.log it out to the screen

Comment: You should show your fulle server main source file... I suppose you use express, but details are important to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see here is that you donpt shot the content-type of your client request.
If you use for example

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

than the correct way to pass POST data is:

```
body: JSON.stringify({prod: prod1})
```

Comment: Wonderful! But so, why did you accept and upvote other and later asnwers? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add `application/json` as header's content type and use `JSON.stringify({yourKey:yourData})` as the body.

**Client:**

```
function addToCart(prod1) { 
 fetch( '/addToCart' , { 
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
   method: ' POST ',
   body: JSON.stringify({prod : prod1 })
 }); 
}
```

**Server:**

```
app.post("/addToCart", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.prod);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't try to send a json object instead a string?

```
data = {
  prod: prod1
}

function addToCart(data) { 

 fetch( '/addToCart' , { method: ' POST ', body: JSON.stringify(data) }); 

}
```